# Google Play Console Play App Signing - The Android App Bundle was not signed

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I am trying to create a playstore release.

I've followed the guide to create an upload key and keystore, to the letter: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key

I have then generated a signed app bundle of my app with the upload key, exactly as stated here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release

Which resulted in a file named: `app-release.aab`

Now, because this app is brand new, and has never been released before, there is no need to export the encrypted key and "opt in an existing app into Play App Signing" as I already opted in to this when I created the new app listing in the play console and, of course, I've never uploaded an APK signed with another key for this app listing before.

Next, I  go to the play console and create a new production release. When I upload the `app-release.aab` file however, I see the following error message:

`"The Android App Bundle was not signed."`

Which is completely baffling.

As far as I can tell, I have followed the instructions **to the letter**, and I have attempted to do some research on google but I'm finding no answers.

Could anyone with experience of this process help me?

EDIT:

What I did not understand about the entire process, was that I am asked to generate the upload key locally but never actually upload the key to the google play console - how on earth does Google know that the app is signed with the upload key, if they've never seen the upload key? But, no where in the documentation of generating the upload key is it stated that I am supposed to do anything with the locally generated key other than use it to generate the signed app bundle locally, which is exactly what I have done.

EDIT 2:

Here are screenshots showing the process I am following to create the upload key and generate a signed bundle of my app with the upload key:

[image: Generating the keystore]

[image: Generating the signed app bundle part 1]

[image: Generating the signed app bundle part 2]

[image: Successfull generation of signed app bundle]

[image: Resultant aab file]

And then, rather oddly, the result of running `keytool -printcert -jarfile app-release.aab` from the directory where the bundle is:

[image: Not a signed jar file]

Answer (score 5):

I tried building a release package that was set to 'debuggable true' to upload to my test-channel, to debug the release key hash and got this problem. I thought I had ruined something trying to get the key hash with keytool and openssl, like that I changed something that made it stop working, but it was just because I made the release debuggable in the build.gradle buildTypes. Just a helpful thought to those who comes here next in case they have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can verify if the app bundle you upload to Play is signed by running locally one of the following commands:

Using jarsigner:

```
jarsigner -verify app.aab
```

Using keytool:

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app.aab
```

If it says the file is "verified" (or you see the certificate being printed when using keytool), then you AAB is indeed signed. If it is, make sure you upload the right file to Play Console, and if it still doesn't work, contact the developer support.

If it says the file is *not* verified/signed, then make sure you have selected a keystore in Android Studio when you generated the signed bundle and ensure the build succeeds.

If all else fails, do a full *Clean Project* and try again.

> how on earth does Google know that the app is signed with the upload key, if they've never seen the upload key?

Google simply extracts the certificate from the first APK or AAB you upload and considers this the upload certificate. Every subsequent upload will have to be signed with the same key, but the first one can be signed with anything.

Comment: Thanks for the testing tips, I'll go and try this now. And the last paragraph makes sense, I had a hunch it worked like this.

Comment: Wow, well it does indeed say "Not a signed jar file" when I run this command against the generated file.

However, I am 100% certain I am doing the correct thing to generate the signed bundle.... I will upload screenshots into the original question to show how I am generating the signed bundle and then locating the outputted artifact

Comment: If you have time Pierre, check my screenshots in the updated OP?

Comment: This looks right. I'm not sure what could be causing the issue. You could try filing a bug against Studio. Have you tried doing a clean build, that sometimes miraculously fixes things for some reason.

Comment: Funny, I have the same problem and you posted it just 2 days ago. But why didn't you mark the checkbox there? I did.

Comment: @ThomasCook I recently ran into a problem with building a signed APK (documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176501/why-does-androidstudio-fail-when-building-signed-apk-for-google-play-says-bad-p/72176588#72176588)  that is very similar -- except I had (2 years ago) already gen'd a JKS file and now it was saying it couldn't be used.

Comment: @raddevus - this is "kind of" what has happened to me! I generated a new JKS file, and pointed AS to it when trying to generate a signed AAB, it would "succeed" and output an unsigned AAB. After much hair pulling, I found out the actual build.gradle file was still pointing at the old JKS (which no longer existed...). I changed the build.gradle file to point at the new JKS and it worked. So, seems like an AS bug, silently swallowing errors?

Answer (score 0):

I had to rebuild the project before signing it.

Comment: Worked for me too. I solved some problems because rebuild went wrong and then it started working.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar problem (just a few days ago).

I was able to resolve my problem (and I don't know why) by running the following command on my .jks file and then going through Android Studio and generating the signed app bundle again.

> $ keytool -list -keystore 'fakeNmae.jks' -storepass
> fake-password-same-one-i-used-in-android-studio

Use the command exactly as you see it except of course replace your .jks file name with the one above (make sure it is between single quotes) and then add your password after the -storepass command.

Hope it helps you too.

Here's the entry I [posted here on SO about the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176501/why-does-androidstudio-fail-when-building-signed-apk-for-google-play-says-bad-p).