# Google PLay Console gives this error: "The Android App Bundle was not signed."

Tags: android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-signing

Google Play Console gives this error: "The Android App Bundle was not signed."
I wasn't able to find a fixing answer yet.
I have been working on it for nearly a week without any success.
Chat Help with google didn't help.

E.g. I'm not sure if this gradle setting is OK:

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
    }
```

[image].

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72227185/4265103

Comment: @Pierre THis is good but for the thing that I'm getting this error: `$ ./jarsigner.exe
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

`

Comment: You need to install a JRE. But more importantly you may want to look at what fixed it for them and try that

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this problem in the future.
Just make sure that in the release buildType you don't have the debuggable set to true

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        debuggable false
    }
}
```